Socket.io does not seem to work with React.useEffect
I followed this tutorial https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/real-time-notification-system-using-next-js-and-socket-io/ which describes 3 parts: the servers that issue the notification web site, the form for sending the notification and the page for displaying the notification. Server app and notification sender works fine.
But page that displays messages does not work as intended. Although I can successfully receive the message (displayed in the browser logs), it does not written into the notifications variable using the setNotifications function.
console.log(`Notification from server`, data);

this line shows that data variable contains correct data received from websocket server.
console.log(`Notifs - `, notifications);

but this line shows empty notifications array.
Here is the full code of page that receives notifications.
"use client"
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import socketio from "socket.io-client";

function Notifs({notifications}) {

    console.log(`Notifs - `, notifications);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {notifications.map((notification, index) => (
                <div key={index}>
                    <h1>Name: {notification.name}</h1>
                    <span>Message: {notification.message}</span>
                </div>
            ))}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default function Home() {
    const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([]);

    const socket = socketio.connect("http://localhost:4000");

    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log(`Connected to server`);
        });

        socket.on('notification', (data) => {
            console.log(`Notification from server`, data);
            setNotifications(prev => [...prev, data]);
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log(`Disconnected from server`);
        });
    }, [socket]);

    return (<>
        <Notifs notifications={notifications}/>
    </>);
}

For example similar modification of the code above works just fine, though it does not use useEffect hook.
"use client"
import React, {useState} from "react";

function Notifs({notifications}) {

    console.log(`Notifs - `, notifications);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {notifications.map((notification, index) => (
                <div key={index}>
                    <h1>Name: {notification.name}</h1>
                    <span>Message: {notification.message}</span>
                </div>
            ))}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default function Home() {
    const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([]);

    const AddMe = () => {
        const data = {name: 'just', message: 'works'};
        setNotifications((prev) => [...prev, data]);
    };

    return (<>
        <Notifs notifications={notifications}/>
        <button onClick={AddMe}> Add me</button>
    </>);
}

